# Exercise with table and defined structure

Tags: c

I'm learning programmation in C and found the following exercise:

> Write a program that gets the full name, age, address and sex of 2 players and then show them.

I used one header:

```
#ifndef DEF_MAIN
#define DEF_MAIN

typedef struct Person Person;
struct Person
{
    char name[100];
    char pname[100];
    char address[1000];
    int age;
    int sex;
};

#endif
```

And here's the main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "main.h"

static void search(char *chain)
{
    char *p = strchr(chain, '\n');

    if (p)
    {
        *p = 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Person player[2];
    int k=0;
    for(k=0;k<2;k++)
    {
        printf("The player %d's family name?",k+1);
        fgets(player[k].name,100,stdin); // The size of the chain is 100 as defined in the header.
        search(player[k].name);
        printf("The player %d's first name?",k+1);
        scanf("%s",player[k].pname);
        printf("The player %d's address?",k+1);
        scanf("%s",player[k].address);
        printf("The age of player %d?",k+1);
        scanf("%d",&player[k].age);
        printf("The player %d's sex? 1 if boy and 0 if girl.",k+1);
        scanf("%d",&player[k].sex);
    }
    k=0;
    for(k=0;k<2;k++)
    {
        switch(player[k].sex)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("\nInfos player %d:\nFamily name: %s\First name: %s\nAddress: %s\nAge: %d ans\nSex: Boy\n",k+1,player[k].name,player[k].pname,player[k].address,player[k].age);
            break;
        case 0:
            printf("\nInfos player %d:\nFamily name: %s\First name: %s\nAddress: %s\nAge: %d ans\nSex: Girl\n",k+1,player[k].name,player[k].pname,player[k].address,player[k].age);
            break;
        }

    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use fgets instead of printf so that if the user enters a space with keybord, there's no bug on the program.

When I test the program and write in family name Scientifica for exemple, the program works correctly. But when I write Scien Tifica, everything works correctly except for family name of player 2: The program skips the fgets but executes correcly scanf. When it reach the last printf, nothing is showed in the family name of player 2.

I don't know where my code is wrong. Please can you help me?

Comment: Why aren't you using fgets for the address as well?

Comment: I'm just testing it for name. If it doesn't work, then it won't work even for address.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&player[k].sex);` --> `scanf("%d%*c",&player[k].sex);` for skip newline.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works! Gonna test now using fgets for first name and address.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY but when I didn't use %*c, the newline exist and after it, a printf is executed and then fgets, so please how does %*c influences on it?

Comment: newline after the number is consumed by fgets. It becomes empty input.

Comment: So this happens even if there are functions before the fgets like printf in this case?